# main function already defined in ocaml asmrun library

Tags: c++, c, ocaml, ffi

I'm trying to call some ocaml code from a C program. I've been following some of the documentation [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#s%3Aembedded-code). The c program is called `hello.c`, and it is attempting to use Ocaml functions defined in `callme.ml`.

As in the link, I'm doing this in two steps: first compile the ml file to an object file:

```
ocamlopt -output-obj -o callme2.o callme.ml
```

And then attempt to link it to my 'main' binary with this code:

```
gcc  -Wall -I`ocamlopt -where` -L`ocamlopt -where` -lasmrun -lm -ldl  -o hello hello.c callme2.o -lasmrun
```

But I run into the following problem: `main` is already defined in libasmrun.a, and so it conflicts with the `main` in my own `hello.c`:

```
/tmp/ccANhYNH.o: In function `main':
hello.c:(.text+0x58): multiple definition of `main'
/home/orm/.opam/4.02.0/lib/ocaml/libasmrun.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

How can I work around this?
(As the library path suggests, I'm using ocaml version 4.02)

**update:** this problem has more to do with proper usage of C linker flags, rather than ocaml. Using the flags in the following order fixes the problem:

```
gcc  -Wall -I`ocamlopt -where` -L`ocamlopt -where` -o hello hello.c -lasmrun callme2.o -lm -ldl -lasmrun
```

This is interesting, because I thought it was illegal to have the same function name defined twice in the [same program](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).  Maybe this is one of the exceptions in that document.

Comment: Why do you have a `main` in your library? `main` should be used only for the entry point.

Comment: Your C code can have a `main` as long as it calls `caml_main`.

Comment: @meneldal: There is a main in `hello.c` and one in the static library. This needs to be this way because it is a c program calling ocaml code.  Ocaml doesn't know about this c program. The library has its own main for some reason, the library is a standard ocaml library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line is a little strange, as `-lasmrun` shows up twice.

Here's something that has worked for me:

```
$ W=`ocamlopt -where`
$ gcc -I $W -L $W -o hello hello.c callme.o -lasmrun -lm -ldl
```

You can see a working example in my pseudo-blog: [Further OCaml GC Disharmony](http://psellos.com/2015/01/2015.01.gc-disharmony-bis.html).

(As I learned the hard way, make sure you follow the rules of GC harmony :-)

Comment: Quick question. the symbols is indeed defined twice, so why is it legal given one flag ordering but illegal given a different ordering?

Comment: I'm not an expert. But I think it works like this. The linker takes the first symbol it finds in a library to satisfy an external reference. If it finds the `main` in asmrun first, it takes it. But the symbol in hello.o doesn't have library semantics, it is always included. If the linker sees asmrun before hello.o there is a problem. If it sees hello.o first, it no longer has an unsatisfied reference so it doesn't care about the `main` in asmrun.